# $a=\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}$ then what is the value of $a^5+a^4-2a^3-7a^2-7a+16$?

Tags: calculus

> $$a=\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}$$
> then what is the value of
> $$a^5+a^4-2a^3-7a^2-7a+16 $$

I tried to factorize the formula, but even wolfram alpha has no result.

Perhaps the formula should make some change. The answer of this question is 20(integer!), but I don't know how to make it easier, and I really want to know if their is any tips to deal with this kind of formula.

Any help is appreciated, thank you~ :D

Comment: The question as stated asks for the value of the expression.  But, you say the answer is 20, suggesting that the value is 20 (I don't know if this correct myself).  So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$a^3=2+\sqrt3+2-\sqrt3+3(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)(2+\sqrt3+2-\sqrt3)$$

$$\implies a^3-3a-4=0$$

$$a^5+a^4+2a^3-7a^2-7a+16$$

$$=a^2(a^3-3a-4)+a(a^3-3a-4)+5(a^3-3a-4)+?$$

Comment: Ah! I got it! $=a^2(a^3-3a-4)+a(a^3-3a-4)+5(a^3-3a-4)-4a^3+12a+36$=0+0+0-16+36=20

Answer (score 1):

Cubing $a$ should give you $a^3 -3a = 4$. Can you take it from here?